# Upgraded 10 turn potentiometers don't work whereas the original 1 turn potentiometers do. Why?

Tags: power-supply, resistance, datasheet, potentiometer, linear

I bought [this](http://www.banggood.com/0-30V-2mA-3A-Adjustable-DC-Regulated-Power-Supply-DIY-Kit-p-958308.html) adjustable power supply kit and successfully assembled it. I wanted to upgrade the potentiometers to 10 turns so I could have fine control over the current and voltage limits set. Both potentiometers are 10K ohm and I have tested both to make sure they were in that range. For some reason, the output of the board drops somewhere like -0.5V when I try to use the upgraded potentiometers but works fine with the originals. What is causing this?

[These are similar to the originals, only without the rear two pins (all i could find)](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/B103-10K-potentiometer-with-switch-single-joint-liner-5-pins-potentiometer-shaf-length-15MM-loud-speaker/32478029846.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_6,searchweb201644_4_505_506_503_504_10020_502_10014_10001_10002_10017_10010_10005_10006_10011_10003_10021_10004_10022_10009_10008_10018_10019,searchweb201560_5,searchweb1451318400_-1,searchweb1451318411_6450&btsid=78671d7c-e5d7-4b49-aa28-586a27e0f5f7)

[These are the upgraded potentiometers](https://www.bourns.com/pdfs/3590.pdf)

Comment: User error - incorrect wiring, damaged PCB when desoldering the original pot, etc. I don't think anyone will be able to answer this without more details like photos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll make a WAG on this- the wiper is typically the rear terminal in 10-turn helical pots (vs the middle terminal on single-turn pots), so if you wired the middle terminal to where the wiper should go it wouldn't work well.

Note that Bourns numbers the terminals 2-1-3 from the back (see the drawing).

Comment: Yeah that was it. I guess i know now for the future to check BOTH terminals in reference to what i believe is the wiper. Much appreciated!

Comment: It's not a bad idea to play with the original potentiometers and the new ones with a multimeter set to Ohms mode; by doing this you can easily discover which two nodes are the terminals of the main resistive element, and which is the wiper.

Comment: As @Kaz says, btw you were lucky the pot was not destroyed- if it's connected as a voltage divider and you turn the wiper to minimum resistance the expensive pot can be fried.